# Ubuntu 18.04 Change the Login Screen to use an image such as a png file

Tags: login-screen

I have tried all suggestions for changing the user LOGIN screen background to use an image file. So far no joy! Obviously, I am missing something some where. Can anyone give me the steps to change the user LOGIN screen. Not the desktop background and not the lock screen!

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

- Run Terminal with Ctrl + Alt + T
- Run nautilus with sudo by doing (sudo nautilus) - without the brackets
- Copy your desired background image to /usr/share/backgrounds/
- Go to /etc/alternatives/gdm3.css and open with Text Editor

**Change This**

```
  #lockDialogGroup {
  background: #2c001e url(resource:///org/gnome/shell/theme/noise-texture.png);
  background-repeat: repeat; }
```

**To This**

```
  #lockDialogGroup {
  background: #2c001e url(file:///usr/share/backgrounds/yourimage.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center; }
```

Click 'Save' when you're done.

Restart your PC